# number of solution of a trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the number of positive solutions of $cos(97x)=x$ ?

I think the answer is $1$. But the book I am studying says that the number of solutions is $31$.

Comment: Looking at [the plot of the function $f(x)=\cos(97x)-x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos(97*x)-x+from+-2+to+2) should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If we change to polar graphs, we can work this out.  Change $x$ to $\theta$.  The graph of $r=\cos 97\theta$ is a 97-petaled rose curve of radius 1, with the first petal straddling the $x$-axis.  The graph of $r=\theta$ is a spiral that starts at the origin and tangent to the positive $x$-axis.  It increases going counter-clockwise and intersects the first petal once and every other petal twice, until $r=\theta >1$.  So we just need to count how many petals there are in 1 radian.

There are $97$ petals in $2\pi$ radians, so there are $97/2\pi =15.43$ petals.  The first half-petal is intersected once, and the other 15 twice, for a total of 31 intersections.